# Method not found: 'System.String RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplate.Run

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, razorengine

I'm trying the new Azure Mobile App. Created the instance in Azure, and then downloaded the Visual Studio package. Updated all components via Nuget. And now when I run it, am getting following error :

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Method not found: 'System.String RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplate.Run(RazorEngine.Templating.ExecuteContext)'.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.MissingMethodException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Content.HtmlActionResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()</StackTrace></Error>
```

Found another post that recommends to upgrade Windows Azure Mobile Services, which I have done so.

Am running Razor Engine 3.7.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with RazorEngine v 3.5 and above. Working fine with 3.4.2.

https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/284